# matlab variables save as python format

Tags: python, matlab, format

Now I have an output variable in `MATLAB` look like this:

```
'mdb.jobs['EXAMPLE2']._Message(END_STEP, {'phase': STANDARD_PHASE, 'stepId': 1, '
    '    'jobName': 'EXAMPLE2'})'
    'mdb.jobs['EXAMPLE2']._Message(COMPLETED, {'phase': STANDARD_PHASE, '
    '    'message': 'Analysis phase complete', 'jobName': 'EXAMPLE2'})'
    'mdb.jobs['EXAMPLE2']._Message(JOB_COMPLETED, {'
    '    'time': 'Wed Jul 01 10:54:57 2015', 'jobName': 'EXAMPLE2'})'
```

I'd like to save this variable as python file, i.e. save as `.py` file. Is there any command I can do this? I tried `save` command but I don't know what is the abbreviation for `Python` in `MATLAB` ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, you want to save a variable in MATLAB and load it into Python.  For this, the file format is irrelevant as long as it stores the variable, can be saved in MATLAB, and can be read by Python.

What you want to do is save a `.mat` file in MATLAB, and load it into Python.  You can do this with the `scipy` package and its `scipy.io.loadmat` function.  However, you must first configure MATLAB to save files in the `v6` format, rather than the `v7` or `v7.5` format used by default in more recent MATLAB versions.

Your stated goal won't work, because MATLAB doesn't support writing to Python data formats.  That is why you need to save in a MATLAB format.

Also, a `.py` file is the equivalent of a `.m` file, not a `.mat` file.  It is a file for holding code in a text format, not a file for holding data.  You can't "save a variable as a `.py`" file any more than you can "save a variable as a `.m` file".

Python does have files roughly equivalent to `.mat` files, particular `pickle` files and `.npz` files.  But MATLAB has no support for them.